# Finding an explicit formula for a sequence

Tags: pattern-recognition

Suppose we have the sequence

$$ \left(0, {3\over5}, {4\over5}, {15\over17}, {12\over13},{35\over37},\ldots\right).$$

Is it possible to find an explicit formula $a_n$? I cant seem to find one.

Comment: These pairs are a part of Pythagorean triplets.

Comment: The denominator is always the hypotenuse and the sequence looks to be strictly increasing.

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit Well-spotted!  So they appear to be the sines of the acute angles of right triangles with rational sides, in increasing order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the rule to generate your sequence, you may prove by induction that:

$$a_n=\frac{n^2-1}{n^2+1}, n\ge 1$$

Comment: does not work.....

Comment: It works for your set...

Comment: check a_3 .....

Comment: $a_3=8/10=4/5$. Similarly, $a_5=24/26=12/13$ etc

Comment: @almagest, thanks :)